# Zip list of different lengths

Tags: haskell

I'm just starting with Haskell and I'm not sure how to do this but when I have an input like [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] the output should be [[(1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8)][(1,9),(2,10),(3,11),(4,12)]]. I tried to do something, see my code below. But this only works for a list of a specific size. I'm sure there must be a way to do this more efficiently and for a list of any size recursively, can someone help me with this?

```
splitlist :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a,b)]] 
    splitlist list1 list2 = [a,b,c] where
        n = length list1
        a = zip list1 list2
        nlist = drop n list2
        b = zip list1 nlist 
        nnlist = drop n nlist 
        c = zip list1 nnlist
```

Comment: What if `[1,2,3,4`] and `[5,6,7,8,9,10]` ->  `[[(1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8)],[(1,9),(2,10)],[(3,9),(4,10)]]`?. The question is unclear.

Comment: What should the output of `splitlist [] [1]` be?

Comment: @Redu Sorry about that, all the elements of the second list should only be used once. So the output would be [[(1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8)],[(1,9),(2,10)]] It's like how a function works, every x (elements of the first list) can only have one y-value (the elements of the second list).

Comment: @DanielWagner I didn't think about that, for code I tried to wrote above it would give the empty list. But let's just assume the lists that are given will never be empty.

Comment: Only the first list needs to be assumed non-empty; `splitList xs [] = []` fits the general pattern, as my recursive answer puts to good use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right approach, but you just need to make it recursive rather than enumerating the number of cycles you go through:

```
splitList :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a,b)]]
splitList as [] = []
splitList as bs = zip as bs : splitList as (drop (length as) bs)
```

So, for example,

```
splitList [1,2] [1..10]
  == zip [1,2] [1..10] : splitList [1,2] [3..10]
  == zip [1,2] [1..10] : zip [1,2] [3..10] : splitList [1,2] [5..10]
  == ...
  == zip [1,2] [1..10] : zip [1,2] [3..10] : ... : zip [1,2] [9,10] : splitList [1,2] []
  == zip [1,2] [1..10] : zip [1,2] [3..10] : ... : zip [1,2] [9,10] : []
  ...
  == [[(1,1),(2,2)],[(1,3),(2,4)],...,[(1,9),(2,10)]]
```

Comment: Just what I needed! It fixes the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: This is probably inefficient for a large second list; I think that can be fixed by simply making it strict in the second argument.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, thank for the heads up.

Comment: When the first list is longer, this doesn't cycle the second list.

Comment: Er, stricter, anyway (or it won't work on infinite lists).

Comment: @DanielWagner True; I'm not sure if that is a requirement, though.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting question! `cycle` may help in this situation, it repeat the elements of list infinite time, such as

```
cycle [1,2,3,4] = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,....]
```

so, when to zip with `[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` will be the desired result `[(1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8),(1,9),(2,10),(3,11),(4,12)]` and then use [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) (defined in Data.List.Split) group it into `[[(a, b)]]` type as:

```
splitList::[a]->[b]->[[(a,b)]]
splitList [] _ = []
splitList _ [] = []    
splitList list1 list2 
    | length list1 <= length list2 = doSplit (length list1) (cycle list1) list2
    | otherwise                    = doSplit (length list2) list1 (cycle list2)
    where doSplit len xs ys        = chunksOf len $ zip xs ys
```

**P.S this solution only work for finite lists**

Comment: But beware that this forces both lists into memory (and consequently definitely doesn't work if one of the lists in infinite). That probably doesn't matter, because this really seems more like a learning exercise than something you might actually want to do; but in case it does matter, with some care it should be possible to force only the shorter list and an equally-long prefix of the longer list to be in memory at once (and work correctly even with infinite lists).

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks your opinion, I have remark it in answer. Since `[a]` and `[b]` are different type and their elements are not instance of`Eq` class, I can't use `isPrefixOf`,  and `length` function cannot apply to infinite list,  besides use `length` function, do you have any suggestion to compare the length of two list? or don't need compare their length?

Comment: Okay, I've written up what I have in mind for avoiding calling `length`.

Answer (score 2):

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53695905/849891) isn't working when first list is the longest of the two; the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53695540/849891) seems excessively long for such a simple task.

It is easy to amend the first answer's code,

```
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

splitList as bs = zs : if null xs then map ( zip  as) (chunksOf n ys)
                                  else map (`zip` bs) (chunksOf n xs)
   where
   (zs, n, xs, ys) = (zip as bs, length zs, drop n as, drop n bs)
```

Works in both cases, also with infinite lists.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer shows how to reuse library functions. However, it has a small flaw: it forces its arguments into memory before beginning to return results, so it doesn't play cleanly with the rest of Haskell's lazy infrastructure. In this answer, I will show how to write a version which:

1. Begins producing output immediately (as soon as it is clear that both lists are nonempty)
2. Works with infinite inputs
3. Forces at most twice the length of the shorter list worth of elements into memory at any given time

We will build up all the pieces used in the other answer, but lazified versions of them: rather than using `Int` for lengths, we'll implicitly use a list of type `[a]` as a lazy representation of its own length. The first thing we need is comparisons of two lazy numbers. It will turn out later to be convenient to have our comparison return not just which number is bigger, but the difference of the two numbers, as well.

```
data LazyOrdering a b
    = LazyLT [b]
    | LazyEQ
    | LazyGT [a]
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

lazyCompare :: [a] -> [b] -> LazyOrdering a b
lazyCompare [] [] = LazyEQ
lazyCompare [] bs = LazyLT bs
lazyCompare as [] = LazyGT as
lazyCompare (ah:at) (bh:bt) = lazyCompare at bt
```

Next we need `chunksOf`; we will implement it in terms of a lazified version of `splitAt`. The latter should take a "lazy" length to split its list argument at. We are careful to start producing elements as quickly as we can -- that is, as soon as we know that the index to split at is greater than 0 and the list we're splitting is nonempty.

```
lazySplitAt :: [a] -> [b] -> ([b], [b])
lazySplitAt [] bs = ([], bs)
lazySplitAt _ [] = ([], [])
lazySplitAt (_:as) (b:bs) = (b:bb, be) where ~(bb, be) = lazySplitAt as bs
```

Our lazy `chunksOf` variant can now use `lazySplitAt` as a subroutine. Again, we take a "lazy" number as our first argument; and we are careful to produce the structure of the output list as early as possible, calling `(:)` as the outermost function call.

```
lazyChunksOf :: [a] -> [b] -> [[b]]
lazyChunksOf as bs = bb : case be of
    [] -> []
    _  -> lazyChunksOf as be
    where ~(bb, be) = lazySplitAt as bs
```

With these pieces in place, we can use essentially the same implementation, swapping in our lazy variants for `length`/`(<=)`/`chunksOf`.

```
zipCycle :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a,b)]]
zipCycle [] _ = []
zipCycle _ [] = []
zipCycle as bs = zip as bs : case lazyCompare as bs of
    LazyLT bt -> lazyChunksOf as (zip (cycle as) bt)
    LazyEQ    -> []
    LazyGT at -> lazyChunksOf bs (zip at (cycle bs))
```

We can try it out in ghci:

```
> zipCycle "hi" "hello"
[[('h','h'),('i','e')],[('h','l'),('i','l')],[('h','o')]]
```

Infinite lists work well as either argument:

```
> take 3 $ zipCycle "hi" [1..]
[[('h',1),('i',2)],[('h',3),('i',4)],[('h',5),('i',6)]]
> take 3 $ zipCycle [1..] "hi"
[[(1,'h'),(2,'i')],[(3,'h'),(4,'i')],[(5,'h'),(6,'i')]]
```

...or as both arguments:

```
> take 1 . map (take 3) $ zipCycle [1..] [1..]
[[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]]
```

Comment: I really like this solution, it covers a lot of things I didn't think about! But it's also really advance for a beginner like me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank for your answer and detailed explanations.

Comment: "forces its arguments into memory before beginning to return results" absolutely wrong.

Comment: @WillNess It was righter before the answer it was referring to got deleted. =)

Comment: @DanielWagner should I undelete my answer?